# How to change site from Team Site to Publishing Site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, branding

I am developing a website that needs branding. It will have my own logo, color scheme, menu, images e.t.c. As far as I have understood, to make such a website, I need to create the site as "Publishing Site" and not "Team Site" or "Document Workspace" e.t.c.

Is my understanding correct?

Secondly if let's say I have made my site as "Team Site" and later I realized I need to change it to "Publishing Site" so I can do branding, can I change site's type to "Publishing Site"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate two features on team site:

1. SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (site collection scope)
2. SharePoint Server Publishing (web scope)

Comment: Ok so after that "Team Site" will behave like a "Publishing Site"?

Comment: You will have all functionality that is accessible in a publishing site.

Comment: I enabled "Publishing Infrastructure" and "Publishing" but I don't see "Page Layout" option on home page of ribbon? Does it mean you also need to make page as "Publishing"?

Comment: It looks like you should create a new page in Pages library and then make it as a start page.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like I am a little late with this response but you do not have to make it a publishing site just to apply branding.  Most branding can be achieved with CSS which can either be applied at a site level or on specific pages as needed.  If a custom master page is actually required then you can still access the page to select a master page using /_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx - you can also use this interface to apply custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

to apply a brand to a SharePoint site is recommend to activate the publishing features, but you don't need to create a publishing site to apply your brand. I recommend you to take a look on bind tuning there you have a various of skins that you can apply to all of your SharePoint sites, team site, document center, search sites... also if you have a SharePoint on prem you can test the themes during some days with trial versions. http://bindtuning.com is the place where you can brand your SharePoint in just a few clicks