# Master pages selection without SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

Is it possible to create a new default master page in  SPD or edit the default one?
I dont want to enable SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure as it results in problems with templates.
The idea is to create a site collection (1 top site and 3 subs) and then template these out.

According to [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/how-to-change-site-from-team-site-to-publishing-site) it's possible to direcly go to /_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx and select master page however this works only with  SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Hi The answers on that post rely on server side code which is something I want to avoid.  I'm tempted to edit v4.master probably not good practice but should work across templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click on master page in SPD to make it as default or custom master page for the site.

Comment: Hi I've created copy1 of v4.master and made copy1 the default at top level site (using button in ribbon SPD). Then I created a subsite but the copy1 is not being inherited. Can copy1 also be included in all subsites ? If not then maybe edit v4 instead?

Comment: For team sites you need to set the master page individually, you cannot inherit it. So you'd need to define the master page on each sub-team site separately. I've solved it in my cases by creating Feature that is stapled to Team site template and upon creation sets the master page of a new team site to be the same as the master page of the root site collection.

Comment: I've copied copy1 to subsite and made default with spd. So works but manual effort required. Try a few further optuions tomorrow. Thanks